# Prevent IsLockedOut for FailedPasswordAttemptCount

Tags: asp.net, aspnetdb

I have searched for the answer only to find answers about how to unlock a user that is locked in AspNetDb.

Is there a setting I can make in the `web.config` or anywhere else that will prevent an account from getting locked out after "x" number of `FailedPasswordAttemptCount`'s?

Answer (score 1):

As I know there is no setting which prevent an account to be locked if the user exceed **MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts** during **PasswordAttemptWindow** period.

**SqlMembershipProvider** defaults **MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts** to 5 and **PasswordAttemptWindow** to 10 minutes.

But you can set **MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts** to Int32.MaxValue and it will prevent user account to be locked.

```
<membership defaultProvider="SqlMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="SqlMembershipProvider" 
    ... 
    maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="2147483647"/>
  </providers>
</membership>
```